Nested files in item template (Visual Studio 2022)
I want to create template with this three files :

Handler.cs
Feature.Request.cs
Feature.Result.cs

I created these files and modify 'MyTemplate.vstemplate' file content to this  :
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="Handler.cs" >
        Feature.Handler.cs
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Request.cs" DependentUpon="Handler.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">
        Feature.Request.cs
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Result.cs"  DependentUpon="Handler.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">
        Feature.Result.cs
    </ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>

This works fine and it is displayed correctly in solution explorer :

But when i want to create dynamic file name for Handler.cs file
its not work .
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Handler.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">
        Feature.Handler.cs
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Request.cs"  ReplaceParameters="true" DependentUpon="$fileinputname$.Handler.cs" >
        Feature.Request.cs
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Result.cs" ReplaceParameters="true" DependentUpon="$fileinputname$.Handler.cs">
        Feature.Result.cs
    </ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>

but in this case the files are displayed separately: 

Assuming you are working on an item template,hope this will help you for building nested classes:
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Test.cs</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs\$fileinputname$Dependent.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">TestDependent.cs</ProjectItem>

